# How to get all the files from a folder in the Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I would like to get all the file names and their sizes from the a particular folder of a Amazon S3 bucket. I can reach the folder with the following code, but, cant get the fiels inside.

```
public void GetListOfAllS3Objects() {

        System.out.println("Listing objects from the destination bucket");

        ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("my-destination-bucket"));

        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
                System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                        "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
        }
    }
```

To make the question more clear, I have a folder name "molomics" inside the mentioned bucket and I have some `json` and `xml` file there. I would like to get the names for all the files. 
How to do that in the most easy way ?

Comment: Did you have a look at it? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html

Comment: Do you know how would I make these import 
`import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request;`


`import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Result;` in the project, preferably using the `Maven` ?

Comment: Try adding it into maven POM

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.75</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Using this in the `pom`, I get the cant throw the `SdkClientException` error where previously the exception is simply handled by `Exception` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you have to retrieve the S3Object using getObject